# Inputting images into array or matrix elements in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to have a user select images from a folder using the following command in MATLAB:

```
uigetfile('*.tiff','Select the image files')
```

And I wish to write the images into an array or matrix with `n` elements (`n` being the number of images selected in an image selection loop).

I've tried multiple different ways, so any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you kindly.

Here's my most recent attempt:

```
function imagereader

x={};
i=1;

response = 1;

while response ~= 0
    [FileName] = uigetfile('*.tiff','Select the image files')
    x{i} = FileName;

    choice = questdlg('Do you wish to select more images?','Image             selection','Yes','No','No');
      switch choice
          case 'Yes'
              response = 1;
              i+1;
          case 'No'
              response = 0;
      end
end

while i >= 1
    image(x{i})
    i-1;
end
```

Comment: What are those different ways you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended your example. Hope it helps:

```
function imagereader

x={};
i=1;

response = 1;

while response ~= 0
    [FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.tiff','Select the image files');
     [FileName,PathName]
    x{i} = imread([PathName, FileName]);

    choice = questdlg('Do you wish to select more images?','Image             selection','Yes','No','No');
      switch choice
          case 'Yes'
              response = 1;
              i+1;
          case 'No'
              response = 0;
      end
end

while i >= 1
    figure;
    imshow(x{i});
    i = i-1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Marcin.

A last question: When I print out the array, only the very FIRST image gets printed. Is there any way I could see all the images printed out in separate windows or figures? Preferably, a grid?

Thanks again!

Comment: @JonahPeltz Just put `figure;` before `imshow`. this will create and display images in separate figures.

Comment: Strangely, it prints out only one figure. Is there perhaps a possible explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The most stright-forward way would be to store the images in a cell array with `n` cells:

```
filenames = uigetfiles('*.tiff','Select the image files', 'multiselect', 'on' );
n = numel(filenames); % number of files selected
imgs = cell( n , 1 ); % pre-allocate space
for ii=1:n
    imgs{ii} = imread( filenames{ii} );
end
```

If all your images are of the same size, you may stack them into a 4D (color images) / 3D (gray-scale images) arrays.

Comment: Thank you Shai. Could you explain the ii part, and why the brackets contain a 1 in cell( n , 1)? I'm not sure I follow.

Here's my code, and it doesn't seem like the last loop is working. I get an error message that the array must be numerical and/or logical...

Comment: @JonahPeltz you get an error because `x{i}` in your second while loop is `char`. Its only a file name, not the image date.